# getmodel error for custom admin module. grid is blank

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, grid, module, setup-script

I am using magento 1.8.
And creating custom admin module called **manoreport**, In single admin module I have 3 functionality **fees, donation, commissionconfig**, Seperate controller and block for each functionality. And I am creating custom table for only commissionconfig [table name is commission_config], I am getting this install script in core_resource table, and table commission_table also created when I refresh the page.

Here is the config.xml file code for the new table and resources

```
 <global>
        <models>
            <manoreport>
                <class>Npm_Manoreport_Model_Commissionconfig</class>
                <resourceModel>manoreport_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </manoreport>
            <manoreport_mysql4>
                <class>Npm_Manoreport_Model_Mysql4_Commissionconfig</class>
                <entities>
                    <commission_config>
                        <table>commission_config</table>
                    </commission_config>
                </entities>
            </manoreport_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <commission_config_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Npm_Manoreport</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_config_setup>
            <commission_config_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_config_write>
            <commission_config_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_config_read>
        </resources>
```

But in commissionconfig grid, when I call the function

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('manoreport/commission_config')->getCollection();
```

Its blank and I am not getting grid.

In my model folder. I have these files.
Npm/Manoreport/Model/Commissionconfig

```
<?php
class Npm_Manoreport_Model_Commissionconfig extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('manoreport/commissionconfig');
    }
}
```

Npm/Manoreport/Model/Mysql4/Commissionconfig

```
<?php
class Npm_Manoreport_Model_Mysql4_Commissionconfig extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('manoreport/commissionconfig', 'commissionconfig_id');
    }
}
```

Npm/Manoreport/Model/Mysql4/Commissionconfig/Collection

```
<?php
class Npm_Manoreport_Model_Mysql4_Commissionconfig_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('manoreport/commissionconfig');
    }
}
```

What is my fault? Why I am getting blank page in grid and blank collection.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charlie here
Models in declareation
Just change

```
<entities>
    <commission_config>
    <table>commission_config</table>
    </commission_config>
</entities>
```

to

```
  <entities>
        <commissionconfig>
        <table>commission_config</table>
        </commissionconfig>
    </entities>
```

As you have

```
manoreport/commission_config change manoreport/commissionconfig change
```

Thus:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('manoreport/commissionconfig')->getCollection();
```

Comment: Tanks a lot. :)